# Get statistic for author on max date less than or equal to a certain date

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query is pseudo code for what I am trying to do.

This does not work in the fact that the popularity is not the one on the `max(dt)`.

```
select authors,max(dt),popularity from author_info.performance 
where dt<='20070201'
group by authors
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without a join?

There are N so many authors with a one to one mapping for `author.max(dt).popularity` (to express the end result in "." notation).

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to check the condition in `HAVING` clause like

```
select authors,
popularity 
from author_info.performance 
group by authors
having max(dt) <= '20070201';
```

Comment: and the dt would be distributed properly per author?

Comment: Yes kind of, you are just bringing the condition to check max(dt) less than provided date.

Comment: i need popularity per author at their max(dt), given that max(dt) per author is <= x

Comment: @jasonm, try the query in answer first. if it's doesn't gives expected result then let me know what wrong went exactly.